# volume down button stuck on android phone

Tags: safe-mode

Yesterday i dropped my HTC one M8 pretty badly and it fell straight on it's side. Specifically straight on the volume down button, denting the metal in that area causing the volume down button to be permanently pressed. Now i could deal with not using the volume down button but i ****ed up and restarted the phone. Now every time it restarts it goes into recovery mode. I can boot into safe mode by holding the volume up key on boot. I cant boot the phone normally now. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can't free it, your going to have to bring it somewhere to have it serviced.

Comment: Try to open the battery cover and then free the button.use lot of patience and a sharp object to open it.find images on web with open cover m8.